# Roles, Permisos asp.net c# sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Buenas quisiera que me puedan ayudar estoy realizando en lenguaje Programacion **asp.net c#** y **sql server** roles y permisos de usuario:

Tengo estas Siguientes Tablas en Sql Server :

**Tabla Roles**

```
ID_Roles    Rol_Cargo   Rol_Estado
  1       ADMINISTRADOR    1
  2        LOGISTICA       1
  3           LIMA         1
  4            JOS         1
```

**Tabla Usuario**

```
ID_Usuario  Usu_Username    Usu_Pass    Usu_Estado
  1           pflores        123456         1
  2           CMARALLANO     123456         1
  3           DCOLLANTES     123456         1
  4            DYLLESCAS     123456         1
```

**Tabla Usuario_Roles**

```
ID_Usuario_Roles    ID_Usuario  ID_Roles
    1                      1     1
    2                      2     2
    3                      3     3
    4                      4     4
```

**Tabla Menu**

```
ID_Menu       Men_Nombres                      Men_Estado
1         Registrar Servicios Red Lima            1
2         Registrar Servicios Red Provincia       1
3         Registrar Nuevos Suministros            1
4         Reporte Todos los Meses                 1
5         Pago Servicio Red Lima                  1
6         Pago Servicio Red Provincia             1
```

**Tabla Menu_Roles**

```
ID_Menu_Roles   ID_Menu ID_Roles
    1              1       1
    2              2       1
    3              3       1
    4              4       1
    5              5       1
    6              6       1
    7              1       2
    8              2       2
    9              3       2
   10              4       2
   11              5       3
   12              6       4
```

Por lo que estoy desarrollando es segun el usuario que ingrese debe mostrarse el menu segun el tipo de usuario.

Por lo cual tengo este procedimiento almacenado que se ingresan.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_ValidarUsuario]
@username varchar(350),
@llave varchar(350)
as
begin

SELECT a.Usu_Username,d.Men_Nombres FROM Usuario a
inner join Usuario_Roles b
on a.ID_Usuario=b.ID_Usuario
inner join Menu_Roles c
on b.ID_Roles=c.ID_Roles
inner join Menu d on c.ID_Menu=d.ID_Menu
WHERE a.Usu_Username=@username AND Usu_Pass=@llave --a.Usu_Username='pflores' and a.Usu_Pass='123456'   --@username AND Usu_Pass=@llave

end
```

por lo que yo cuando ingreso con el usuario ya me captura que menu debe ir en este caso por ejemplo le puse del administrador y este es el resultado del procedimiento en la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando lo realizo en el asp.net c# en el menu no se como hacer que se visualize la verdad quisiera que me ayuden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En algún proyecto hice algo similar, para eso lo que hice fue que en la tabla que tu llamas "Tabla Menú" se agrega una columna que contenga la pagina, link o procedimiento que se debe llamar al seleccionar la opción del menú y ya con esta campo adicional llamas el procedimiento almacenado y lo almacenas en una tabla o lista y con esta construir el menú es muy sencillo.

En el lugar donde vas a ubicar el menu pon lo siguiente:

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Mode="PassThrough"></asp:Literal>
```

y en el code behind carga la consulta que ya te funciona en un datatable (supongo que esa parte la tiene clara) y luego de eso construyes un string con los "items" del menu, finalmente ese string lo envias al objeto literal:

```
DataTable menu = GetData(query);
        string mppal = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < menu.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            mppal += "<li><a runat=\"server\" href=\"" + menu.Rows[i][2].ToString() +
                "\" style=\"color: #FFFFFF\">" + menu.Rows[i][1].ToString() + "</a></li>";
        }
        Literal1.Text = "<nav> <ul id=\"menu\">" + mppal + "</ul> </nav>";
```

Comment: podrias poner un ejemplo por favor si me podrias ayudar te lo agraderia

Comment: Es un proyecto antiguo para webforms no se si le sirva...

Comment: carlos donado claro todo sirve yo tambien estoy haciendo en webforms c#

Comment: Carlos Muchas Gracias si me resulto :D te lo agradesco :D

Comment: Con mucho gusto, esta comunidad es para ayudarnos